# Using 'on conflict' with a unique constraint on a table partitioned by date

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, database-partitioning, postgresql-11

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE event_partitioned (
    customer_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    event_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    comment varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    event_timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NOW()
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (event_timestamp);
```

And partitioning by calendar week [one example]:

```
CREATE TABLE event_partitioned_2020_51 PARTITION OF event_partitioned
FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-12-14') TO ('2020-12-20');
```

And the unique constraint [event_timestamp necessary since the partition key]:

```
ALTER TABLE event_partitioned
    ADD UNIQUE (customer_id, user_id, event_id, event_timestamp);
```

I would like to update if customer_id, user_id, event_id exist, otherwise insert:

```
INSERT INTO event_partitioned (customer_id, user_id, event_id)
VALUES ('9', '99', '999')
ON CONFLICT (customer_id, user_id, event_id, event_timestamp) DO UPDATE
SET comment = 'I got updated';
```

But I cannot add a unique constraint only for customer_id, user_id, event_id, hence event_timestamp as well.

So this will insert duplicates of customer_id, user_id, event_id. Even so with adding now() as a fourth value, unless now() precisely matches what's already in event_timestamp.

Is there a way that ON CONFLICT could be less 'granular' here and update if now() falls in the week of the partition, rather than precisely on '2020-12-14 09:13:04.543256' for example?

Basically I am trying to avoid duplication of customer_id, user_id, event_id, at least within a week, but still benefit from partitioning by week (so that data retrieval can be narrowed to a date range and not scan the entire partitioned table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `on conflict` in a partitioned table. You can, however, express the logic with CTEs:

```
with 
    data as ( -- data
        select '9' as customer_id, '99' as user_id, '999' as event_id
    ),
    ins as (  -- insert if not exists
        insert into event_partitioned (customer_id, user_id, event_id)
        select * from data d
        where not exists (
            select 1 
            from event_partitioned ep
            where 
                ep.customer_id = d.customer_id
                and ep.user_id = d.user_id
                and ep.event_id = d.event_id
        )
        returning *
    )
update event_partitioned ep  -- update if insert did not happen
set comment = 'I got updated'
from data d
where 
    ep.customer_id = d.customer_id
    and ep.user_id = d.user_id
    and ep.event_id = d.event_id
    and not exists (select 1 from ins)
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB -- I wonder if there a possibility of a race condition here, with millions of transactions per day.

Comment: @sqldoug: that's a single query, so it runs "atomically", and there is no risk of race condition: the database manages concurrency for you. Performance is something else of course: this will probably be less efficient than a straight `on conflict` statement.

Answer (score 0):

@GMB's answer is great and works well. Since enforcing a unique constrain on a partitioned table (parent table) partitioned by time range is usually not that useful, why now just have a unique constraint/index placed on the partition itself?

In your case, event_partitioned_2020_51 can have a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE event_partitioned_2020_51
    ADD UNIQUE (customer_id, user_id, event_id, event_timestamp);
```

And subsequent query can just use

```
INSERT ... INTO event_partitioned_2020_51 ON CONFLICT (customer_id, user_id, event_id, event_timestamp)
```

as long as this its the partition intended, which is usually the case.